# Таблицы стилей для IE

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Если к странице делается таблица стилей для ие, и при этом оказывается, что в разных версиях ие для одного и того же элемента нужны разные значения одного и того же свойства, в этом случае нужно писать несколько дополнительных таблиц стилей для каждой версии ие

```
<!--[if IE 8]> 
<link href="css/ie8-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> 
<link href="css/ie7-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

или как-то можно совместить всё в одной таблице стилей, но чтобы каждая версия ие считывала то, что написано для неё?

Comment: если по правильному, то как у вас выше.

Comment: да? а мне казалось, что я неправильно что-то делаю, раз у меня несколько таблиц стилей под каждый ие. спасибо!)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну так и сделай.
пишешь общий стиль, а потом под какждые нужные персии переопределяешь для нужные стили в других файлах.

Comment: понятно, спасибо)